# Omniauth not working well for me in rails 3.1.0rc8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I am using omniauth for twitter authentication and any time i try localhost:3000/auth/twittet i get the following error

```
OAuth::Unauthorized 
401 Unauthorized
```

pls any ideas to this issue cos i cant get it right. I have omniauth in my gem file and followed a screencast by ryab bates and just the first step and i have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by specifying a proper callback URL and set your application type to browser. Try http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter

Also, ensure you're using the correct `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`